# extjs 4 designer 1.2 grid renderer

Tags: grid, extjs4, renderer

i m working with extjs designer 1.2. I have a button on panel that opens window on click. The window has grid for which i have applied renderer as following in js file . The problem is renderer works well when the window opens up for first time, but when i close window & reopen it, the effect goes off.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.TestWindow', {
    extend: 'MyApp.view.ui.TestWindow',

initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;
    me.callParent(arguments);

}

 });
```

==========================================================================

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.TestPanel', {
    extend: 'MyApp.view.ui.TestPanel',

initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;
    me.callParent(arguments);
    Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('Test').load();
    me.down('button[id=testbutton]').on('click',me.onTestBtnClick,me); 
},

onTestBtnClick:  function(){

    var win = new Ext.create('MyApp.view.TestWindow');
    win.show();
    win.down('#testgrid').columns[0].renderer=function(val){
         return '<span style="color:red;">' + val + '</span>';
        }

}
});
```

**Observation :**  When i use renderer in ui.js i.e. the file generated by exporting project from designer, i dont face above stated problem. What can be solution for this problem?

Comment: Have a look at the generated code (ui.js) or post it here, so we can have a look and find something when comparing the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved similar issues caused by the `closeAction` config option of my `Ext.Window` *(`MyApp.view.TestWindow` in your case)* being set to `hide`, instead of `destroy` *(Ext JS 4 default)*. Your illustrated button click event handler instantiates a new `Ext.Window` *(`MyApp.view.TestWindow` in your case)* every time it is fired. If these instances are not created and destroyed properly you may experience DOM `ID` contention and undesirable results.

If your goal is to persist such instances a better approach, regardless of the state of your current config options, would be for you to relocate your instantiation logic to a global scope and only manage the `show`ing and `hide`ing of this component in your button click event handler.

Because you have not provided the underlying `MyApp.view.TestWindow` logic, I am only left to assume that the root cause of your issue does pertain to a combination of either misconfigured config options and/or component instance management, ultimately resulting in components contending for the same DOM `ID`.

Another thing to be mindful of is the use of statically defined `id` config options. If you are statically defining an `id` config option on any component you must ensure that those components are either singletons, or their instances assigned in a global scope for reuse. Again, this all boils down to proper component management.

Lastly, it is also a possibility that the use of my suggestion does not reveal any glaring issues specific to your `MyApp.view.TestWindow`. If this is the case, inspect and ensure that none of the underlying `MyApp.view.TestWindow` child components *(grid, column model, column, etc.)* are culprit.

**EDIT**

**Below is an example:**

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.TestPanel', {
    extend: 'MyApp.view.ui.TestPanel',

initComponent: function() {
    var me = this;
    me.callParent(arguments);
    Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('Test').load();
    me.down('button[id=testbutton]').on('click',me.onTestBtnClick,me);

    me.testWindow = new Ext.create('MyApp.view.TestWindow');
    me.testWindow.down('#testgrid').columns[0].renderer=function(val){
        return '<span style="color:red;">' + val + '</span>';
    }
},

onTestBtnClick:  function(){
    var me = this;
    me.testWindow.show();
}
});
```

Comment: hey thanx @timothy..i have added TestWindow code in my ques just in case u want to have a look & can find smthin worth changing..

Comment: I've added an example of what I was referring to. Also, I didn't notice this last night as it was super late, but you should be defining your renderer directly in your grid column config rather than  where you are now. I hope that works for you.

Comment: sorry for late feedbk..had got stuck in some other extjs prob..It worked..Apart from ur code, I added closeAction:hide to my window config & it works perfectly now. Thanx a lot for all time & effort.